# NSMutableDictionary not saving to local directory

Tags: objective-c, nsmutabledictionary, writetofile

I test to see if a directory is saving and it doesn't seem that it is.

Here is what I have, it's essentially creating a list of which files have been uploaded to Dropbox. DropboxList is declared in the header file and then synchronized.

int i = 0;

```
DropboxList = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];

do {

[DropboxList setObject:@"NO" forKey:[NSNumber numberWithInt:i]];

i++;

} while (i < sortedFiles.count);

NSLog(@"dropbox list is %@", DropboxList);


NSArray *dropBoxPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *dropBoxDocumentsDirectory = [dropBoxPaths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *dropBoxDataPath = [dropBoxDocumentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"/DropboxUploads"];

if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:dropBoxDataPath]) {
    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtPath:dropBoxDataPath withIntermediateDirectories:NO attributes:nil error:nil];
}

NSString *filePath = [dropBoxDataPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"dropboxList.out"];

[DropboxList writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];

NSMutableDictionary *newDictionary = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:filePath];

NSLog(@"newDictionary list is %@", newDictionary);
```

Here is my console:

```
dropbox list is {
    0 = NO;
    3 = NO;
    2 = NO;
    1 = NO;
    4 = NO;
}
newDictionary list is (null)
```

I've tried alloc init for the newDictionary before writing and I get the same result. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with the following line

```
[DropboxList setObject:@"NO" forKey:[NSNumber numberWithInt:i]];
```

DropboxList `writeToFile` only works with the valid property list. For a `NSMutableDictionary` to be a valid property list object, its keys should be string type instead of `NSNumber`.

**Solution**

```
[DropboxList setObject:@"NO" forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",i]]];
```

Also, make use of the `writeToFile` return parameter to validate.

```
BOOL isWritten = [DropboxList writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
if (isWritten)
{
    NSMutableDictionary *newDictionary = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
    NSLog(@"newDictionary list is %@", newDictionary); 
{
else
{
    NSLog(@"Something went wrong");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so my problem was that I had NSNumbers as the keys, which doesn't work. I made the keys strings, and we're golden.